# Roku player issue when i play the video url

Tags: roku

I am not able to play below URLs in my Roku play. But it will play directly in my browser. Could you please help anyone to resolve this issue.i am getting error code -3 and -5Please find the URLs belowurl==https://player.vimeo.com/external/374187070.hd.mp4?s=830905100ab32a09782c69bb2cd65b87886fa767&profil...
url==https://player.vimeo.com/external/374187611.hd.mp4?s=97375190f8f86387cabd506f1f9778f79fd8d3f9&profil...
url==https://player.vimeo.com/external/374178410.hd.mp4?s=69b820de8ba67fad5a1f564305caadaeebd3df89&profil...

Comment: Please show how you're setting the `content` to the `Video` node.

Comment: please look the below answer

Comment: You should have edited your question not added an answer.

Comment: I getting the same problem with HTTPS Streams. First I getting -3 Error code and I added certificate like below. Here the same thing my video URL is mp4 and It's Working fine with Google Chrome. `m.video.GetCertificate File("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt") m.video.InitClient Certificates()` After, I getting a -2 Code "Connection timeout".

Answer (score 0):

I try below to play but can't

```
 videoContent = createObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
 videoContent.streamformat = "mp4"
 'httpAgent = CreateObject("roHttpAgent")
 'videoContent.HttpSendClientCertificate(true)
 videoContent.Addheader("x-roku-reserved-dev-id","")
 videoContent.SetCertificatesFile("pkg:/source/testCA.CRT")
 videoContent.InitClientCertificates()
 videoContent.url = "https://player.vimeo.com/external/374178410.hd.mp4? 
 s=69b820de8ba67fad5a1f564305caadaeebd3df89&profile_id=170"
 videoContent.title = "Test Video"
 videoContent.StarRating = 80
 videoContent.Length = 1972
 m.videoPlayer.content=videoContent
 m.videoPlayer.control = "play"  
 m.videoPlayer.visible=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating the Http agent but not setting it.
E.g in my channel I do

```
 httpAgent = CreateObject("roHttpAgent")
 video = m.top.createChild("Video")
 video.setHttpAgent(httpAgent)
 video.AddHeader("Authorization", "My Custom Auth Header")
```

Before moving on to the video player logic.
Note that since I'm using a custom server with password protection, I pass a custom header- I'm not sure what the auth flow is for Vimeo, but it might be useful to read.